# Why and when is feeds_entity_load needed

Tags: feeds

I have the feeds module enabled and when I load a basic view, it generates 688 calls to the function `feeds_entity_load` which generate as many database query, which degrades the performance.

Why are these call needed ? For me `feeds` is only use to import data, so why is it impacting every single page load ? I'm thinking of deactivating this function but I would like to understand if it's safe to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why and when is feeds_entity_load needed

It isn't.

`feeds_entity_load()` was [removed from the Feeds module 3 years ago](https://www.drupal.org/node/1661014). It no longer exists in the codebase (download and `grep -nr feeds_entity_load feeds`, the only reference you'll find is in the changelog).

You should upgrade your version of feeds ASAP, you must have an outdated version installed.

Comment: You are right, but strangely, when drupal thinks my version is up to date and doesn't propose me to update it.